# Proving uniform convergence of a polynomial sequence

Tags: real-analysis

If $f(x) = |x|$ on $[-1,1]$. How do I show that a polynomial sequence $P(x)$ such that $P(0) = 0$, converges uniformly to $f$ on $[-1,1]$?

-Is it true to say that since $f(x)$ is continuous on the interval, then by WAT there's a polynomial converging uniformly. But I guess this isn't specific for my polynomial.

-What about this, that the supremum is when the $x\rightarrow0$.

Comment: please don't confuse "polynomial" with "sequence of polynomials"

Comment: Just for reference, Rudin addresses this question in Corollary 7.27 of his _Principles of Mathematical Analysis_ (third edition).

Answer (score 1):

This is a consequence of Stone Weirstrass since $f$ is continuous

Comment: S.W shows that there is some polynomial, not necessarily the polynomial that I gave. right? Please elaborate a little on this, I may not be familiar with polynomials.

Comment: you can modify the sequence $P_n$ given by into  $P_n-P(0)$.